# In GVIM or awk or sed, How do I paste a column of text from a different file after a different column of text in another file?

Tags: sed, awk, vim

In GVIM How do I paste a column of text from a different file after a different column of text in another file?

-regards

[image]

Comment: That's not very honest to change the scope of your question after it was correctly answered.

Answer (score 8):

In the source window, select the column with *visual-block* mode and yank it.

In the destination window, place your cursor on the last character of the first line of the first column (adding a few spaces if needed) and hit `p`.

[image: demo]

Source window:

```
<C-v>G$y
```

Change window:

```
<C-w>w
```

Destination window:

```
A<Space><Space><Esc>p
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select the desired columns with <kbd>Ctrl-v</kbd> (<kbd>Ctrl-q</kbd> if you use mswin.vim mappings), yank, them paste on the second file. See `:h visual-block` for additional information.